# Granting a role which appears in session_roles (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm creating and granting a role as ADMIN through these commands:

```
create role X;
grant X to Y;
```

The problem is that user Y, when querying *session_roles*, does not see role X. He can only find it in *user_role_privs* and *dba_role_privs*. The only way to make it appear in the session roles is to run

```
set role X;
```

while logged as user Y, but this seems to be temporary and sometimes fail (when checking *sys_context('SYS_SESSION_ROLES, 'X)* I sometimes get true and sometimes false.

The reason I'm asking is that I need a very fast way to check roles, and using *sys_context('SYS_SESSION_ROLES, 'X)* instead of querying the views for *user_role_privs* and *dba_role_privs* is much faster.

How can I grant a role to Y which appears permanently in session roles? O are there different contexts other than *SYS_SESSION_ROLES* which might work?

Comment: Use `ALTER USER Y DEFAULT ROLE ALL;` or more specific ``ALTER USER Y DEFAULT ROLE X;``

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by logging as ADMIN and running

```
ALTER USER Y DEFAULT ROLE ALL;
```

This forces all the roles to appear as session roles.